# ZARN bearings vs thrust tapered bearing pairs

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

Does anyone know how needle assemblies like [this](https://www.abf.store/s/en/bearings/ZARN3585-TV-A-INA/847787) stack up against having a pair of thrust tapered bearings back to back in terms of radial and axial load? That is, a bearing like this:

[image]

as opposed to this:

[image]

Comment: What do the bearing manufacturers provide in terms of information? Speed rating, load rating axial & radial etc?

Comment: @SolarMike What I've found is the following (35mm bore): Ca - 56000 N / Dynamic load rating (axial)

C0a - 148000 N / Static load rating (axial)

Cr - 26000 N / Dynamic load rating (radial)

C0r - 47000 N / Static load rating (radial) It's not clear to me how the ratings should be derived for back-to-back thrust tapered ones.

Comment: So, how do those values stack up against the values in your application?

Comment: For a pair of opposing TRBs you can double the radial load rating of a single bearing, assuming they are sharing the load. But only one bearing can accept thrust at a time, so the axial rating of one bearing is the rating for the pair.